# Calling Find Function Twice gives undefined as output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Following code works fine the first time, It finds the correct item and changes its checked value, but if I call the same function with the same id again it returns undefined. any idea why?

This code is using in a React Native Application where the checkbox is updated using this method

CheckBox :

```
<CheckBox value={item.checked} key={item.id} onValueChange={setSelection} onChange={()=> {
handleChange(item.id);
}}
style={styles.checkbox}
tintColors={{ true: "#ffc324", false: "#ffc324" }}
/>



const handleChange = (id) => {
const ids = id;
let changedCheckbox = categories.find((category) => {
    return category.subcategory.find((item) => {
        if (item.id === ids) {
            return (item.checked = !item.checked);
        }
    });
});
console.log(changedCheckbox);
};
```

This is the JSON I use

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "MOTs",
    "filename": "1610270182.png",
    "bg_filename": null,
    "content": "You can try this set a state like this and check if your component mounted or not. This way you are sure that if your component is unmounted you are not trying to fetch something.",
    "featured": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-01-10T09:16:22.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-01-10T09:40:37.000000Z",
    "subcategory": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MOT1",
            "category_id": 1,
            "image_name": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "MOT2",
            "category_id": 1,
            "image_name": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "MOT3",
            "category_id": 1,
            "image_name": "1611678308.png",
            "created_at": "2021-01-26T16:25:11.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-26T16:31:24.000000Z",
            "checked": false
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleChange = (id) => {
  const category = categories.find(category => {
    const item = category.subcategory.find(item => item.id === id);
    if (item) item.checked = ! item.checked;
    return !!item;
  });
  console.log(category)
};
```

Toggle checked then return boolean not `checked`.

Comment: Jehong : No Change :(

Comment: @BinuMathew OK. I will try again.

Comment: @BinuMathew What do you mean `item.checked = !item.checked`? Do you want to toogle checked?

Comment: yes, if it's true, then need to change it to false, if false then true

Comment: @BinuMathew Don't change value in the `find` callback. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Any idea why we cant change value in find ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232789/discussion-between-binu-mathew-and-jehong-ahn).

Comment: @BinuMathew Please read my current answer.

Comment: Thks @Jehong, It actually worked but the problem is it's now showing only one subcategory from the JSON, how can I update the whole JSON with a updated subcategory?

Comment: @BinuMathew OK. I rewrite my answer. Only difference with your code is, my code returns boolean not `checked`.

Answer (score 0):

change this statement

```js
return (item.checked = !item.checked);
```

what you are doing when it is false it will return true, the next time its value is true so it will return false
do this instead

```js
if (item.id===ids){
item.checked = !item.checked;
return true;
}
```

Comment: can you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4pbhgn5o/, it seems to be working for me.